# Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration' when running test

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, applicationcontext, mockmvc

I'm creating a Spring Boot application with Spring Security. I've created a custom login page that uses an auth endpoint in our `AuthController`. My `SecurityConfiguration` class extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

At the moment, I'm trying to create tests for this without any results. Most of this is new to me and I'm still learning, specially testing. I'm not even sure if I've done this right at all.

Any help is appreciated.

**SECURITYCONFIGURATION**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final ApplicationUserService applicationUserService;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(  "/register", "/index*", "/static/**", "/*.js", "/*.json", "/*.ico").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                //.loginProcessingUrl("/api/auth/authenticate")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(applicationUserService);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

**AUTHCONTROLLER**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/auth/")
public class AuthController {

    private final UserService userService;


    @PostMapping("authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<?> verifyUser(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
        return userService.authenticateUser(user);
    }

}
```

**USERSERVICE**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(User user) throws Exception {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getEmail(),user.getPassword()));
        if (!authentication.isAuthenticated())
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseObject("Error"), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        else {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(user,HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }

}
```

**TESTCLASS**

```
@WebMvcTest(AuthController.class)
class AuthControllerTest {

    User user;

    @MockBean
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        user = User.builder()
                .email("test@hotmail.com")
                .password("password")
                .id(1L).build();
    }

    @Test
    void verifyUser() throws Exception {
        given(userService.authenticateUser(any(User.class))).willReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK));

        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/auth/authenticate")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(user)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

**ERRORS**

> Failed to load ApplicationContext java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration' defined in file [\SecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {} Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: Does the controller work if you make a call to it? Is it just the test that fails? Can you post the code of your SecurityConfiguration class?

Comment: @Jeroen Everything works as planned. We've tested this manually, with our client and postman.
But the problem is testing this so we have coverage.